# How do I create a httppost getting same parameters from httpget?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, http-post, http-get

I have a controller to show up a model (User) and want to create a screen just with a button to activate. I don't want fields in the form. I already have the id in the url. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hidden field inside the form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

or pass it in the action of the form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", 
    new { id = RouteData.Values["id"] }, FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: But i cant have httpost and httpget with same paramets, can you show the sample for .cs too ?

Comment: @waldecir, no, you can't have two controller actions with the same arguments. You will need to modify the signatures of either your GET or POST action.

Comment: Yes i know. my firt page is a get with id to show the infos about user, so i need a post to activate/deactivate, how would be the httppost call?

Comment: @waldecir, you have two possibilities: either rename your controller action to make the compiler happy and still use the `[ActionName("Index")]`  along with the `[HttpPost]` attribute to make this action accessible with the same name as the GET action, or add some dummy action parameter to it.

Comment: Thnkx very much, i thinkg the best option is create a new action, and use the second solution with routes, sice i dont need any model information, do you agree?

Comment: @waldecir, yes that's an option.

Answer (score 24):

Use [ActionName] attribute - this way you can have the URLs seemingly point to the same location but perform different actions depending on the HTTP method:

```
[ActionName("Index"), HttpGet]
public ActionResult IndexGet(int id) { ... }

[ActionName("Index"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexPost(int id) { ... }
```

Alternatively you can check the HTTP method in code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    if (string.Equals(this.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party on this but I found an easier solution to what I think is a fairly common use-case where you prompt on GET ("are you sure you want to *blah blah blah*?") and then act on POST using the same argument(s).

The solution: use **optional parameters**. No need for any hidden fields and such.

Note: I only tested this in MVC3.

```
    public ActionResult ActivateUser(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActivateUser(int id, string unusedValue = "")
    {
        if (FunctionToActivateUserWorked(id))
        {
            RedirectToAction("NextAction");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

On a final note, you can't use string.Empty in place of `""` because it must be a compile-time constant. And it's a great place to put funny comments for someone else to find :)

Answer (score 1):

My approach is not to add an unused parameter as that seems like it would cause confusion, and is in general bad practice.  Instead, what I do is append "Post" to my action name:

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int id)
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUserPost(int id)
{
    // Do work here
    RedirectToAction("ViewCustomer", new { customerID : id });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for such simple situation is to give a name to submit button and check in action if it has value or not. 
If it has the value, then it Post action, if not, then it Get action :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", 
    new { id = RouteData.Values["id"] }, FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="btnActivate" />
<% } %>
```

For Cs you can combine get and post controller methods in one:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, string btnActivate)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(btnActivate))
        {
            Activate(id.Value);
            return RedirectToAction("NextAction");
        }

    return View();
}
```