# How to Prevent Validators from Running on HttpGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, controller, .net-core

After reading [this very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196838/35142) I modified a pair of methods to allow them both to accept the same view model:

```
[ActionName("AddressCorrection"), HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddressCorrectionGet(AddressCorrectionViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);  // was return View();
}

[ActionName("AddressCorrection"), HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddressCorrectionPost(AddressCorrectionViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Index", new ApplicationViewModel { SuccessMessage = "That worked." });
    }

    model.ErrorMessage = "Something went wrong";
    return View(model);
}
```

Problem is, calling `return View(model);` in `AddressCorrectionGet` now treats the invocation as a `POST` of sorts. Specifically, the validators on `AddressCorrection.cshtml` run. Instead of seeing a blank form ready for input, I see a form with a bunch of “required fields missing” messages.

How do I prevent the View from running the validators in this case? Or in the more general case, how does the View know that it should vs. should not run validators (I was thinking this was simply based on whether the Request method was `GET` vs `POST`. Clearly wrong.), and how can I explicitly tell the view to run or not run the validators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `ModelState.Clear();` before `return View(model);`

Comment: While I don't know *why* this works yet, I do know that this neatly solved my problem. Thank you. I will be reading [this and other related posts here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear) to better understand how this does its magic.